# Is there a way to remove/add applications from/to the slingshot launcher of elementary OS?

Tags: slingshot

Is there a way to modify (remove/add) applications in the slingshot launcher of elementary OS (Freya)? It seems to be easy enough to do so for applications in the Dock.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is now a new application available in AppCenter called: **AppEditor**.

[image: Get it on AppCenter]
[image: AppEditor]

---

Yes. You can use [MenuLibre](https://smdavis.us/projects/menulibre/) for that.

Just search for the App you want to remove and click on "Hide in menu" and than the save button (with arrow down).

[image: MenuLibre Screenshot]

Comment: AppEditor link seems to no longer be working

Comment: For me it still works

Answer (score 5):

You can add/edit menu entries manually, too. Elementary follows the [Free Desktop specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) standard. Basically, you add/edit the *.desktop* files on the global */usr/share/applications/* location or you user location *~/.local/share/applications*, then relogin (or restart the panel app) to see your changes.
Also see their [official doc](https://elementary.io/docs/human-interface-guidelines#app-launchers) and this [blog post](https://devkeep.wordpress.com/2014/02/17/add-custom-application-to-applications-menu-in-elementary-os/) for more info.

Comment: Can I also uninstall Nautilus with AppEditor? I already have Pantheon, I don't get why I have 2 file editors suddenly

Answer (score 2):

You can install a menu editor like `alacarte`:

`sudo apt-get install alacarte`

With it you can add/remove/move menu entries.

Also there is this bugreport about removing
https://bugs.launchpad.net/slingshot/+bug/1211570

Not sure what you want to add...

Comment: Thanks. God to know that a 'bug' report has been submitted for this.